# appUpdateManager return error LinkToDeath

Tags: java, android

I am using an app installed of a closed testers (google play) path, when I start I get error. Is it because I'm using the app as closed testers, or is there a bug in my appUpdateManager code?

```
2021-07-08 23:09:35.053 12389-12389/? I/PlayCore: UID: [10225]  PID: [12389] AppUpdateService : requestUpdateInfo(com.testdev.test)
2021-07-08 23:09:35.054 12389-12444/? I/PlayCore: UID: [10225]  PID: [12389] AppUpdateService : Initiate binding to the service.
2021-07-08 23:09:35.108 12389-12389/? I/PlayCore: UID: [10225]  PID: [12389] AppUpdateService : ServiceConnectionImpl.onServiceConnected(ComponentInfo{com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.installservice.DevTriggeredUpdateService})
2021-07-08 23:09:35.109 12389-12444/? I/PlayCore: UID: [10225]  PID: [12389] AppUpdateService : linkToDeath
2021-07-08 23:09:35.116 12389-12400/? I/PlayCore: UID: [10225]  PID: [12389] OnRequestInstallCallback : onRequestInfo
2021-07-08 23:09:35.116 12389-12444/? I/PlayCore: UID: [10225]  PID: [12389] AppUpdateService : Unbind from service.
```

MainActivity:

```
private static final int REQUEST_APP_UPDATE = 11;

appUpdateManager
                .getAppUpdateInfo()
                .addOnSuccessListener(
                        appUpdateInfo -> {

                            // Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
                            if ((appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE)
                                    && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE))
                            {
                                // Request the update.
                                try {
                                    appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                                            appUpdateInfo,
                                            AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                                            this,
                                            REQUEST_APP_UPDATE);
                                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
```